# Multiple selection listview android with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, checkedlistbox, items

I have followed many tutorials on the web but finally I couldn't get what I want..So finally landed for better suggestions and answers here after all of my research.

I have a listview with checkbox and I need to get all the checked items of listview.

This is my Layout:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/lineItem"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chklist"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:ems="10"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:textColor="#800080"
       android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am using a custom adapter and I'm getting the checked items as shown:

```
holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   String listItemText = holder.txtName.getText()
                            .toString();
                if (holder.chk.isChecked())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Checked" + " " + listItemText,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unchecked" + " " + listItemText,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
              });
```

And how do I get all the checked items from my ListView OnItemClick Listener:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                        View view, int position, long id) {

   //Here  I need to get all the checked items

    }
    });
```

Custom Adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name) {

        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.arr_calllog_name = arr_calllog_name;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemChecked = new boolean[arr_calllog_name.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr_calllog_name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arr_calllog_name.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox chk;
        ImageView editimage, delimage;
        TextView txtName;
        LinearLayout row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chklist);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.row = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lineItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtName.setText(arr_calllog_name.get(position));

        holder.row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*
                 * Intent i = new Intent(AddItems.this, AddItems.class);
                 * Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); // Add your data from
                 * getFactualResults method // to bundle String listItemText
                 * = holder.txtName.getText().toString();
                 * 
                 * bundle.putString("Listname", listItemText);
                 * i.putStringArrayListExtra("AddedList", MyList); // Add
                 * the bundle to the intent i.putExtras(bundle);
                 * startActivity(i);
                 */

            }
        });

        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   String listItemText = holder.txtName.getText()
                            .toString();
                if (holder.chk.isChecked())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Checked" + " " + listItemText,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unchecked" + " " + listItemText,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
              });
        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Comment: @downvoter- Please comment rather than downvoting..so that it will help me to improve my question.

Comment: check this **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Sx1d3Mtpw8**

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter holds all the items of your list. In your case one instance of such an item should at least contain a String (for the textView) and a Bool (for the CheckBox). Whenever you want a list of all the checkboxes, just iterate over your list items and create a temporary list of all the items that have true boolean value.

```
List<YourListItemObject> checkedItems = new ArrayList<YourListItemObject>();

for (YourListItemObject listItem : adapter.getItems()) {
  if (listItem.getBool()) {
     checkedItems.Add(listItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done the same..Can you show me how do I iterate that and If you want I will post relevant parts of my adapter

Comment: see my edit, I added some code example. Maybe you have to cast the Items to "YourListItemObject"...haven't done Java in a while ;)

Answer (score -1):

**Try with this for your multiple selection..**

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        />
```

see this link http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html

Comment: Yes..I agree but how do I get the result? (ie..suppose If I have checked item 1, item2 and item3...I need to get the result as you have selected those 3 items)

Comment: see this link http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html